# Mongomapper map(&:id)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, mongomapper

i have some problems with

```
Click.all.map(&:id).include?(params[:click_id])
```

return false(but click_id present in db)

when im doing

```
Click.all.map(&:id).include?(BSON::ObjectId(params[:click_id]))
```

return illegal ObjectId format

How to do what i want in proper way? return true if object is present

Comment: I hope `params[:click_id]` return `string` and `Click.all.map(&:id)` return array of integers so please try `Click.all.map(&:id).include?(params[:click_id].to_i)`

Comment: yes,params[:click_id]-string,but Click.all.map(&:id) return array of  [BSON::ObjectId('540f07931d41c86ece000022'), BSON::ObjectId('540f07931d41c86ece000023'), BSON::ObjectId('540f07931d41c86ece000024'),etc..]

Comment: Convert it to String. `Click.all.map {|c| c.id.to_s }.include?(params[:click_id])`

Comment: What is the value of params[:click_id]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by converting `id` to a `String`

```
Click.all.map {|c| c.id.to_s }.include?(params[:click_id])
```